# Simple way to solve $(3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}-(2x^2-7x-5)^{1/2}$=$x-5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any easy way to solve this question rather than just squaring both sides and doing lengthy calculations?

Any hint that might help solve this question easily?

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by $(3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}+(2x^2-7x-5)^{1/2} $. That will cancel some stuff.

Comment: One more thing, Just by looking at the equation, can you tell me the maximum number of roots it can have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try to solve $(3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}-(2x^2-7x-5)^{1/2}=x-5$. Multiplying both sides by $(3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}+(2x^2-7x-5)^{1/2}$ gives (after some simplification):
$$
(x-5)(x+5) = (x-5)\left((3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}+(2x^2-7x-5)^{1/2}\right)
$$
Cancelling $x-5$ from both sides give 
$$
(x-5) = (3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}+(2x^2-7x-5)^{1/2}
$$

Adding each side of the equations give
$$
2x-10 = (3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}.
$$
Now we can square both sides.

Comment: That's $2x-10 = 2(3x^2-7x-30)^{1/2}$. And, because you divided by $x-5$, you also need to check if $x=5$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm against this bit of math ed culture that delights in setting hard-looking problems with cute tricks that make them easy. (I have a nice long soap-boxy speech about this.  While not teaching any math, these problems give the impression that math is intractable.)  This problem is no exception.  Fortunately, we can use their arrogance against them.  We assume they're playing some game with us and that the answer is really easy.  So just plug in a few small integers and see what you get.  My first guess was to try $5$ because of the $x-5$ on the right.  And it worked.  It turns out that $6$ also works.  Pah!

If you want to do some math, square both sides, then isolate the remaining radical and square again.  Gather like terms.  You get:

$$8x^4-108x^3+360x^2+500x-3000=0.$$

Divide by $4$:

$$2x^4-27x^3+90x^2+125x-750=0.$$

We know that any rational roots will have numerator dividing $750$ and denominator dividing $2$.  If you try them all, you'll find that $5$ is a root.  Divide by $x-5$ and repeat.  You'll get that $5$ is a root again.  Then $6$.  Then $-5/2.$  You should plug each of these back into the original equation to make sure they aren't extraneous solutions introduced by all our squaring.